# sql substring contains

Tags: sql, regex, if-statement, sas, substring

I have a datasetA with a long narrative field. This field is called "narrative."

I have datasetB full of animal terms, such as "dog", "cat", "mouse". This field is called "animals."

I would like to flag any instance where the animal names are found in the narrative of datasetA, and to create a new field in datasetA, called "animal_found" which pulls that name.

For example, if the word "dog" is found in a narrative, the animal_found field for that record will populate "dog"

if the word "dog" and "cat" is found, the animal_found field will show "dog,cat"

Any thought on how to code this in SQL?

Comment: You have tagged this with both SAS and SQL.  SQL implementations are generally very distinct and SAS's implementation of SQL only support ANSI 92 standard SQL syntax.  If you are doing it in SAS then you probably do NOT want to do it in SQL.

Comment: How big is your word list? I'd recommend loading the second lookup table into a temporary array and then using either Regex or FIND/INDEX to search the words iteratively.

Comment: If you're trying to do keyword searching on data within your tables, SQL is not the way to do it.  Take a look at a package like Elasticsearch that is specifically for keyword searching.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server, there is a way with Dynamic SQL but it's not very elegant nor performant.

```
DECLARE @Animal nvarchar(100)

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY FOR
SELECT Animal FROM datasetB

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Animal
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)
  SELECT @Query = 'SELECT Columns FROM datasetA where narrative like ''%' + @Animal + '%'''
  exec sp_executeSql @Query

  FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Animal
  END

  CLOSE cur
  DEALLOCATE cur
```

The way to do it would probably be to create a temp table or something like that. Then insert the results into your temp table and format it the way you want to. But as I said, cursors are not really performant. But it works

Answer (score 0):

If the list of animals is not too long, try this method and see how it performs. I tested this on SQL Server 2017.

```
with 
cte1 as
(select 'I have a dog, a cat and a bunny as my pets' narrative union all 
select 'I have a horse, a bunny and a dog as my pets' union all 
select 'I have a cat as my pet' union all 
select 'I have a dog as my pet' union all
select 'I have nothing')

,cte2 as
(select 'cat'  animals union all 
select 'dog' union all 
select 'parrot' union all 
select 'bunny' union all 
select 'horse')

select 
narrative, 
string_agg(case when narrative like concat('%',animals,'%') then animals end,',') animals_found 
from cte1 cross join cte2
group by narrative;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f8527bed3114377bfaea0eaada53721c)

Answer (score 0):

Not SQL, but within a data step this can be done relatively easily.

1. load lookup data into a temporary array
2. Loop through list and search text for the data
3. Concatenate results as you loop

**NOTE: This does not handle extra 's' at the end of words, so you may want to consider how you'll handle frog vs frogs since those are technically not the same word. You cannot just switch to find because of partial matches in other words but you could duplicate the loop twice or modify the FIND to check for both at the same time. I'll leave that to you to solve.**

```
    *fake text data;
    data statements;
    infile cards;
    input narrative $100.;
    cards;
    This is some random text with words that are weirhd such as cat, dog frogs, and any other weird names
    This is a notehr rnaodm text with word ssuch as bird and cat
    This has nothing in it
    This is another phrages with elephants
    ;
    run;

    *fake words;
    data words;
    input word $20.;
    cards;
    cat
    dog
    frog
    bird
    elephant
    ;;;;
    run;



    *lookup;
    data want;

    *loads data set M into temporary array M;
    array W(5) $20. _temporary_;
        if _n_=1 then do j=1 to 5;
        set words;
       W(j)=word;
    end;

    *main data set to work with;

    length found $100.;
    found = '';
    set statements;
    do i=1 to dim(w);
    x = findw(narrative, W(i), " ,", 'ir');
    if  x > 0 then found = catx(", ", trim(found), w(i));
    *for debugging, comment out/delete as needed;
        put "N=" _N_ " | I= " i;
        put "Statement = " narrative;
        put "Word = " w(i);
        put "Found = " x;
        put "---------------";
    end;

    run;
```

Answer (score 0):

SAS SQL is the wrong tool for aggregating rows into a concatenation result (csv string).

SQL can be used to obtain the found items to be concatenated and data step DOW loop for concatenating:

```
proc sql;
  create view matched_animals as 
  select narrative, animal from
  narratives left join animals on narrative contains trim(animal)
  order by narratives, animal;

data want;
  length animal_found $2000;
  do until (last.narrative);
    set matched_animals;
    by narrative;
    animal_found = catx(',',animal_found,animal);
  end;
run;
```

This will work but may run out of resources depending on the cardinality of the narratives and animals tables and the matching rate.

A data step approach can utilize hash object, `countw` and `scan`, or `findw`. There are two approaches, with *way2* the probable best / most typical use case.

```
* Thanks Reeza for sample data;
data narratives;
infile cards;
input narrative $100.;
cards;
This is some random text with words that are weirhd such as cat, dog frogs, and any other weird names
This is a notehr rnaodm text with word ssuch as bird and cat
This has nothing in it
This is another phrages with elephants
;
run;

data animals;
input animal $20.;
cards;
cat
dog
frog
bird
elephant
;;;;
run;

data want;
  set narratives;

  length animals_found_way1 animals_found_way2 $2000;

  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    if 0 then set animals(keep=animal); * prep pdv;
    declare hash animals(dataset:'animals');
    animals.defineKey('animal');
    animals.defineDone();
    declare hiter animals_iter('animals');
  end;

  * check each word of narrative for animal match;
  * way 1 use case: narratives shorter than animals list;
  do _n_ = 1 to countw(narrative);
    token = scan(narrative, _n_);
    if animals.find(key:token) = 0 then 
      animals_found_way1 = catx(',', animals_found_way1, token);

    loopcount_way1 = sum (loopcount_way1, 1);
  end;

  * check each animal for match;
  * way 2 use case: animal list shorter than narratives;

  do while (animals_iter.next() = 0);
    if findw(narrative, trim(animal)) then 
      animals_found_way2 = catx(',', animals_found_way2, animal);

    loopcount_way2 = sum(loopcount_way2, 1);
  end;  

  put;

  drop token animal;
run;
```